# Workflow for interim codings

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jira

If in two components(Foo and Bar) of a software is a `method signature` change in Foo, we use @deprecated to blame the old method and keep compatibility between Foo and Bar.

**The Problem:**
The XML-Configuration as well as CSS,HTML,JSP ... has no such a Annotation, actually we use TODO in Eclipse as a Marker. The Probem is that its part of the Code we distribute!

**The Workaround:**
In JIRA(+svn-plugin) we blame the code-lines as comments (what is bad practice too).

The Question:

1. Is there a better Solution?
2. Is there a Solution that can manage the impulse to delete this compatibility-only-code.

Comment: The optimal solution would be to change your progress in a way that you don't need "compatibility-only-code". In your case this would mean doing the necessary changes in both components and release them together.

Comment: Why -1? @AndréStannek What if one of the components is 3rd party library?

Comment: -1 wasn't me. If you can change it yourself, it's not really 3rd party. If you can't change it and have fit an API that you use, it's not the kind of "compatibility-only-code" you mentioned. Just a wild guess but in that case the adapter pattern might help you to keep that code seperated.

Comment: You meen a 3rd part library use my jsp,html,css i dont need to take care about compatibility? Tell me how do you make adapter pattern in css/html/jsp!

Comment: What I'm saying is, that if your 3rd party library forces you to do something in a specific way, I wouldn't call it compatibility code. It sure isn't interims code. I don't now your setting (it seems to be a little to complex for this site), but if it's code you don't need anymore later on, perform all the steps to get rid of it immediately instead of later. If there is no way to get rid of it, don't mark it deprecated or something like that in the first place.

Comment: @AndréStannek When do you use `@Deprecated`?

Comment: Ideally never. But generally it is made for members that should not be used anymore. E.g. if you write an API yourself and change it. If some method in it becomes obsolete, you sometimes can't remove it because it is used in other code you can't change. Then you can mark it deprecated as information for other developers that they shouldn't use it anymore. Normally you would document it and specify what should be used instead. See the JLS on that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.6

Comment: Ideally never is subjective. The need of deprecation is objective as you said. The process of the new API includes the removal of the `@Deprecated-Methods`. But a API may contains resources also! I repeat my question: how to deprecate resources!?

Comment: I've never done something like that before. I still find that a strange requirement. I think it's hard to understand without deeper knowledge of your project.

Comment: You may use plugin-tools like Sonar which enforce you to use best practices and  lower your code compliance level if you don't, which level can be used by clients to judge your product's build quality

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you dont want to have `TODO` markers inside distributed text files (noncompiled XML, HTML,...).

I would write a small Groovy* script that removes all those TODO markers (but does not change the semantics of the file). This can be integrated in your build process, so that the distributed code does not contain any TODO markers but these are still in SVN and you can remove them afterwards when you made the new product compatibe.

*Or whatever scripting language you prefer

Answer (score 0):

MyLin may support bookmarks and tasks in future...

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/245439/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, the problem is to remove 'developer notes' (about deprecation as part of) from final distribution. The solution for this is to use some preprocessor, which will strip them from resources and code before compiling and packing final release.
Here is a good sample of such preprocessor: 
  http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/
It can be easily used from any build system or standalone.

Comment: No, the workaround is to remove the developer-notes. I am looking for a solution i may not need developer-notes incode. Like a button in jira "All interim-codings has been removed".

Comment: Sorry, I used Atlassian Jira for years but don't know such button. Can you describe more briefly?